# Python - os.remove() - str object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, string, operating-system, attributes

I've written a script that takes a .csv file, converts it to an .xlsx using openpyxl, and formats the file.

Throughout the script's process, it creates several .csv files, which can be deleted.  I've tried using `os.remove("File.csv")`, but always get the error:

```
      os.remove("File.csv")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I've tried running this on 3 different computers, and I've even written a test script with just 2 lines of code to test the functionality and have had no luck (same error):

```
import os
os.remove("File.csv")
```

Does anybody know the cause/reason for this?

OR

Is there another way to delete (move to trash) a file/multiple files?

Comment: that should work. check if the file.csv is in the same path as you main.py

Comment: I cannot reproduce your second result. In the second example, I get a `FileNotFoundError`. What version of python are you running?

Comment: @Aaseer, it is - I've tried this with multiple files, and I've moved the script and the file to multiple folders with no other files in it.

I'm using version 3.9.2

Comment: Is there another way to delete files?

Comment: How, **exactly** are you running your script?

Comment: I double checked, and I haven't.  I wrote a 2-line script with 'import os', and 'os.remove("File.csv")' in case that has happened, and I still get the same error (see the second code sample above).

Comment: What do you mean @juanpa.arrivillaga?

Comment: I'm mean describe to us in detail how you are running your script (and the test script)

Comment: I have a folder named "Test".  Within that folder, there are 2 files: "RemoveFile.py" (the script), and "File.csv" (the file I want to delete).  I open the script (as usual), and run it.  I've run with VS Code, and the default Python IDLE which can be found here: https://www.python.org/downloads/.  I get the same error in the output from both applications.

Comment: Try checking if the file exists by using `os.path.exists`

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, using os.path.exists fixed it.  I implemented it into the larger script and it worked.  Thanks @Rohith Nambiar

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: Post it as the answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the file using `os.path.exists`
Example:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("File.csv"):
   os.remove("File.csv")
else:
   print("That file does not exist!")
```